# url rewriting issues with YII with redirection

Tags: yii, url-rewriting

Hi I have started developing a webapp using Yii. I have successfully hid the `index.php`.
But I have 2 issues.

1. The admin controller `site.com/admin` is showing the login page for admin.
   After logout I am redirecting back to the index (login page).

   ```
   $this->redirect('index');
   ```

   Although the url is now `site.com/admin/index`, where i would like to hide the `/index` bit. I have tried [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/342/how-to-hide-index-action-from-url/) but that does not resolve the issue.
2. On the admin login page I have following javascript code

   ```
   $("#superlogin").click(function () {
       $.ajax({
           url: "index.php/admin/adminlogin",
           data: $("#adminlogin").serialize(),
           method: "post",
           success: function (data) {
               if (data !== "failure") {
                   window.location.href = "admin/admindashboard";
               }
               else {
                   alert("Please check username and password");
               }
           },
           failure: function () {
           }
       });
   });
   ```

This code works fine when the URL is `site.com/admin` but when the URL is:

1. `site.com/admin/index` - which it becaomes after a logout
2. `site.com/admin/` - trailing slash

the javascript redirect will send me to

`site.com/admin/index.php/admin/adminlogin` in both cases instead of `site.com/index.php/admin/adminlogin`.

What would be the best way to approach this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There are several ways to accomplish this but the easiest one is probably changing your redirect to :

   ```
   $this->redirect('/admin');
   ```

   Even better would be if you relayed on your routes for this. that way, if the config changes, you don't have to change any hard coded links.

   ```
   $this->redirect($this->createUrl("admin/index"));
   ```

   and then to enforce that admin/index is always rewritten to admin you could do this in the `urlManager` (in the config)

   ```
   'urlManager' => array(
       'showScriptName' => false,
       'urlFormat' => 'path',
       'rules' => array(
           'admin/index' => 'admin',
           '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
           '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
       ),
   ),
   ```
2. The best approach in Yii to create the correct URL is always fall back to the createUrl function, even in JavaScript.

   ```
   //Yii.app.createUrl('controller/action');
   //relies on https://github.com/ainsej/Yii-JSUrlManager
   $("#superlogin").click(function () {
       $.ajax({
           url: '<?= Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/adminlogin); ?>',
           data: $("#adminlogin").serialize(),
           method: "post",
           success: function (data) {
               if (data !== "failure") {
                   window.location.href = '<?= Yii::app()->createUrl('admin/admindashboard); ?>';
               }
               else {
                   alert("Please check username and password");
               }
           },
           failure: function () {
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Comment: Sorry , I am getting the `Use of undefined constant Yii - assumed 'Yii'`  . First I tried to use your code directly.Then I put hiddent value and tried to access the createUrl by php `<?php echo Yii.app.createUrl('admin/adminlogin') ?>` but got the same error.Any help, appreciated.

Comment: obviously you are mixing up the js and the php, i made a mistake, the JS createUrl relies on an extention : https://github.com/ainsej/Yii-JSUrlManager I will edit my answer